# Overloading with Polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm designing a physics simulator with 3 types of things that can collide.

The most basic [abstract] class is called `Item` which contains information on mass, position & speed.

There are 3 other types: `Circle`, `Boundary` & `Photon` which extend the `Item` class and have their own properties.

I have a `List<Item>` called `system` which contains various `Circles`, `Boundaries` etc and I go through this list to check for collisions by using a method: `system.get(i).collide(system.get(j));` and this edits the velocities etc.

**My problem is,** Eclipse wants me to have a method in each of the `Circle`, `Boundary`... classes called `collide(Item itemName)` but by doing this the compiler wouldn't be able to treat each type of item differently.

I currently have different methods in the `Circle`, `Boundary`... classes like:

```
collide(Circle c){..}
collide(Boundary b){..}
collide(Photon p){..}
```

But the compiler wants a general `collide(Item i)` method.

How can I satisfy the compiler but still treat collisions with different types differently using inheritance the way I have?

Comment: `system.get(i)` returns an `Item`, the compiler can't know if it's a Circle, a Boundary or a Photon. Thus, the `collide` method must take an `Item` parameter.

Comment: I would suggest that the question that really needs to be answered is *why do you need different versions of the method in the first place*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `collide(Item i)`

But if you want the method to act differently for each super class you can do this:

```
public void collide(Item i) {

    if(i instanceof Circle) { 
      //do something for a circle
    } else if(i instanceof Photon) {
      //do something for a photon
    } else if(i instanceof Boundary) {
      //do something for a boundary
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should Override `collide(Item i)` for each of subclasses. You could check the type of `item` in each implementation, for instance, in your `Photon` class :

```
@Override
public void collide(Item item) {
    if (item instanceof Photon) {
         // implement collision of this with (Photon) item
    } else if ... {
        // I wonder how collision of Photon with Circle would look like :)
    }
}
```

This is quite similar approach to Overriding Object's [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method for new types.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply keep `collide(Item b){..}` or Something like `collide(<? extends Item> b){..}`. You can introduce generics concept here if you are going to pass subtypes also. 
This will give more info about it. http://www.thejavageek.com/tag/generics/

Comment: Could you give me an example? I've never used that type of code before

Comment: @chairharrison, kiruwka has provided a simpler solution :) you can refer it and if you want to study generics then you can study link I've provided